# Unable to print correct character using INT 10H

Tags: assembly, x86, character, x86-16, bios

I have recently tried to make a simple bootloader to learn more about the 8086 Intel CPU. Along the way, I needed a way to print characters to screen. However, when I try to execute the following instructions, I get 'b' instead of 'a' in the QEMU output console.

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

%macro read_sector 6
    pusha
    mov ah, 02H
    mov dl, %1
    mov dh, %2
    mov ch, %3
    mov cl, %4
    mov al, %5
    mov bx, %6
    int 13H
    jc error
    popa
%endmacro%

%macro get_cursor_pos 0
    push ax
    push bx
    
    mov ah, 03H
    mov bh, 0
    int 10H
    
    pop ax
    pop bx
%endmacro%

%macro set_cursor_pos 0
    pusha

    mov ah, 02H
    mov bh, 0
    int 10H

    popa
%endmacro%

mov bp, 0x89B8
mov sp, bp

mov al, 97
loop:
    mov ah, 0AH
    mov bh, 0
    mov cx, 1
    int 10H
    inc al
    ;cmp al, 98
    ;jl loop
end:
    hlt

print_ch:
    pusha
    
    mov ah, 0AH
    mov bh, 0
    mov cx, 1
    int 10H

    ; cmp al, 10
    ; je handle_newline

    ; get_cursor_pos modifies registers dh, dl
    ; get_cursor_pos
    ; inc dl
    ; set_cursor_pos
end_putch:
    popa
    ret

error:
    hlt
handle_newline:
    add dh, 1
    mov dl, 0
    set_cursor_pos
    jmp end_putch

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

But, If I add a `jmp $` before `inc al`, QEMU console shows 'a' as output.

I have no idea about any mistakes in my code. Any help is welcome!

Comment: `hlt` is not a "final" halt ... it wakes up and continues if an interrupt happens (which by default happens due to the clock). You should use it in an endless loop, or disable interrupts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. After I added ```cli``` to before each ```hlt``` instruction, the mysterious character printing disappeared.

Comment: Pay attention to this error: Your *get_cursor_pos* macro restores AX over  BX and BX over AX. Use `push ax` `push bx` ... `pop bx` `pop ax`.